# Cheap Audio Equalizer board converted to seperate outputs

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, band-pass

You can get a cheap ten band equalizer board for about $10.
I was inspired by circuit bending and modifying pre-made circuit boards.
So I wondered if an equalizer such as this could output each of its bands to a separate output jack.

So by soldering 10 pairs of wires to contacts on the board could I get 10 outputs.
My guess is that I can tap into the audio at where the linear resistors connect to the board. With that resistor being what attenuates that band. If not there I would possibly try connecting directly to the output pins of the opamp. The only other obvious connection is solder that is I think each opamps connection to ground.

So basically would this work? Can it still work if I keep the common output? Would cutting the link to the common output help?

For reference this board uses +-5 to +-15v DC. It is apparently a very common design dating back to the 70's if not earlier. Unfortunately I forget the name of this design.

On a small tangent the other circuit bending possibilities I see are as usual changing resistor values.
First replacing the small surface mounted resistors with potentiometer to change the frequency range of the band. The circuit works off of a paring of specific resistor and capacitor values. I am not sure how only changing the resistor would work out. Possibly interesting. Possibly only a very narrow band of working at all. It sounds like it would be more trouble than its worth.

The other interesting possibility is adding a voltage controlled resistor in series with the linear resistors. Such as a cheap led + photoresistor in heat shrink. Such a combination has been used to make diy tremolo pedals with success. Then controlling it with a micro controller to dim the leds in time with an LFO or trigger to open up the eq with decay.

Anyway thank you to anyone who has taken the time to read these musings.

## Update

So things I've learned. The linear resistors are carrying a dc voltage. This voltage ends up being power control for the opamps which along with some resistors and capacitors make up the resonators.

All these resonators have connected inputs and outputs and also connect to one final opamp I have heard referred to as the mixing opamp. I am guessing this last opamp boosts the audio up to usable levels and gets rid of any dc offset.

But my question now is what would you actually get if you connected to the output pins of those opamps?

Would all those pins sound the same? Pre-amplified version of the output?
Would they be different pitches of constructive or destructive noise?

What would it take to make it have separate outputs? Separate opamps and some resistors in some configuration? Or is it basically a nonstarter because the inputs are connected.

Also about the linear resistor, as it controls the resonator opamps, changing them could be useful. But it does not seem easy to physically insert another component there without scraping at the pcb traces. But if I instead had a led/photoresistor connected from the output of the linear resistor, and connected the other side to ground. In an off state it would do almost nothing because the resistance is too high. In an on state it would divide the voltage going to the resistors opamp. But I fear it would possibly cause voltage to flow in the wrong direction through the opamp.

[image: Front of 10 band equalizer]

[image: Back of 10 band equalizer]
[image: Low resolution circuit diagram]

Answer (score 1):

The opamps in this circuit are being used as gyrators, they basically transform a capacitance into an inductance that is then in parallel with another capacitance to form a resonant circuit.
The gyrator is connected to the wiper of a potentiometer which is connected across the inputs of a differential amplifier. The pot varies the gyrator between adding to or subtracting from the original signal to either boost or cut the band of frequencies  around it's center frequency.

You may find some information that will be helpful [here](https://sound-au.com/articles/gyrator-filters.htm) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrator).

Answer (score 1):

The schematic shows how graphic equalizers (when not digital signal processing) are generally constructed. There's no places in the circuit where one could tap a single band.

The principle is an amplifier which has for every band a resonator. The band adjusting potentiometer connects the resonator to affect the gain of the amp, most effectively in resonator's own band. Audio is never splitted to separate filters where one could tap each band. The resonators are equivalents of series LC resonators. The inductors are replaced by by RC-opamp circuits to save space and manufacturing costs. None of the resonators alone is a filter. They are there to make a frequency dependent impedance.